Search for words in a column and return those words if exists in that column Mysql
Mysql
I have a set of words in Column A and Column B consists of set of strings which may or may may not consists of words of column A.
If column B consists of key words of column A anywhere in the full string ,we need to return that particular word from column A.
Please refer to the image for clear understanding. I have given examples of Columns and expected output.Sample
I have tried using case statement and like but not sure how to put the code exactly in order to get the expected output

Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Also show us your current query attempt.

I don't think this is doable in a query as you have to match every word in column1 with every word in column2. Fulltext searches do not accept column as search input, you can only use a string literal there. I don't think mysql is the best tool for this task as its text analytics functionalities are quite limited. I would use python or R for this task.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A pattern:
SELECT {columns}
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON JSON_OVERLAPS( CONCAT('["', REPLACE(table1.textcolumn, ' ', '","'), '"]'),
                              CONCAT('["', REPLACE(table2.textcolumn, ' ', '","'), '"]')
                             )

The query will be extremely slow.. use subqueries which builds JSON arrays and join by the function, such query will be just slow.
